# Show that if the graph has only two vertices that have an odd degree. And then those two vertices have to be in one component.

Tags: graph-theory

> Show that if the graph has only two vertices that have an odd degree. And then those two vertices have to be in one component.

The degree sum has to be an even number to be graphed.

How should I prove?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: There are only two possible graphs with only two vertices. Why not list them out?

Comment: @cr001 only two vertices of odd degree. There may be other vertices of even degree.

Comment: Oh I see. Misunderstood the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Assume to the contrary that they are in different components, and consider the subgraph corresponding to the component of one. Try to obtain a contradiction to what you stated about the sum of degrees in the subgraph.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the two odd-degree vertices, then each component of the graph contains a Euler cycle which visits every vertex in the component at least once. Therefore the two originally odd vertices must belong to the same Euler cycle and therefore when disconnected they belong to the same component as well.